# Trouble with Android AsyncTask Progress Percentage

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, percentage, android-sqlite

I could not think of a way to calculate the progress percentage. I am using JSON to retrieve data then all the data will be insert into sqlite. I wanted to calculate this all process and show a percentage while running asynctask.

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //int progress = 0;  //progress testing
    //while(progress < 100) {
    //progress += 10;
    //SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    //publishProgress(progress);
    //}
        getAllChannels(); //function get json data and insert db.
        return null;
    }
...
public void getAllChannels(){
    try {
            headline = jsheadline.getJSONArray(TAG_NEWLIST);
            headline2 = jsheadline2.getJSONArray(TAG_NEWLIST2); 
            headline3 = jsheadline3.getJSONArray(TAG_NEWLIST3); 
            insertDatabase(headline,TABLE_HEADLINE);
            insertDatabase(headline2,TABLE_HEADLINE2);
            insertDatabase(headline3,TABLE_HEADLINE3);
            }catch (Exception e) {
            }
}

public void insertDatabase(JSONArray total, String tablename) throws JSONException{
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
         for(int i = 0; i < total.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = total.getJSONObject(i);
            // Storing each json item in tablecolumn
            String subject = c.getString(KEY_NEWS_SUBJECT);
                     db.addNews(tablename, subject);
}
```

This are the example on how i store the data into the sqlite. Please guide me out.
Edit: If involve in multiple insert?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onProgressUpdate` supports multiple arguments:

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     int current = progress[0];
     int total = progress[1];

     float percentage = 100 * (float)current / (float)total;

     // Display your progress here
 }
```

You could have your processing method as such:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    JSONArray headlines = jsheadline.getJSONArray(TAG_NEWLIST);
    int count = headlines.length();
    for (int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
        // Insert a single item in the DB
        JSONObject headlineItem = headlines.getJSONObject(i);
        insertDatabase(headlineItem);

        // We have processed item 'i' out of 'count'
        publishProgress(i, count);

        // Escape early if cancel() is called
        if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You also have an example on the [SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: what if multiple insert involve?

Comment: Then you'll need to work a bit to find out the answer. Progress indication is left to you, you only know how to present it. My answer give all the technical info you need to make your own progress algorithm.

Comment: thanks for the info, I manage to get the result by reconstruct my code which is much more better now.

Answer (score 0):

progress report is kinda of subjective and varies a lot depending on what your task is doing, but for your case you could use the `for` to calculate.

```
private int progress;
private int max;

max = total.length()
for(int i = 0; i < total.length(); i++){
   progress = i;
   publishProgress(progress);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how to calculate the value from getAllChannels(), mayb you guide me out?

Comment: oh what you suggest is to manipulate insertDatabase() function. I'll try it out.

Comment: yes. you count your `for loop` and that's the progress. I edited my code.

Comment: what if multiple insert involve?